# Pandas Dataframe: assign to different columns based on positive/negative values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

What I want to achieve is as follows:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  0  0
1 -1  0  0
```

with the above dataframe, regarding column `a`, for positive rows, assign to corresponding rows in column `b`, for negative values, assign to column `c`:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  0
1 -1  0 -1
```

I am now using following code, but is there any way I can write it in one single line instead of two?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, -1], 'b':[0, 0], 'c':[0,0]})
df.b = np.where(df.a > 0, df.a, df.b)
df.c = np.where(df.a < 0, df.a, df.c)
```

Comment: Use `df.assign(b=np.where(df.a > 0, df.a, df.b), c=np.where(df.a < 0, df.a, df.c))`?

Answer (score 0):

I think using `np.where` just fine , if you want them in one signle line

```
s=df.assign(key=['b','c']).set_index('key',append=True).unstack().sum(level=1,axis=1)
s
key    b    c
0    1.0  0.0
1    0.0 -1.0
df.update(s)
df
   a    b    c
0  1  1.0  0.0
1 -1  0.0 -1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I started by writing out

```
df.b, df.c = (df.a > 0)*df.a + (df.a < 0)*df.b, (df.a < 0)*df.a +  (df.a > 0)*df.c
```

then realized you could do the same unpacking with exactly  what you had.  There are any number of ways you can do this in more obscure ways, I guess